# How to evoke Preview's title bar saving dialogue by shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, preview, finder-tag

*Preview* shows the currently opened document’s name in its title bar. When hovering over this name, a arrow appears at the right. After a click, there is a dialogue where you can chance the file name, the file tags, the directory and set the file as protected. This is quite handy if you want to add a tag without opening the file's preferences from the *Finder* view.

How can I open this dialogue using keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Not a real answer, but since you mentioned adding tags, you can create a keyboard shortcut to open the Tagging Menu in Finder, see [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/10/tag-files-keyboard-shortcut-mac-os-x/).

Comment: @thee I have a similar shortcut, but I'd have to leave Preview.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Automator**/**Apple Script** for this with **Mouse Tools** command line app.

You can get **Mouse Tools** from [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html). It's a small tool to move mouse pointer and perform clicks.

```
[-h] return this help text
[-b] coordinates are measured from bottom-left corner of the screen
[-location] return the current mouse location
[-x "xValue" -y "yValue"] move the mouse to the {xValue, yValue} location
[-mouseSteps numSteps] move mouse in number-of-steps to the location
[-leftClick] perform a mouse left-click at the current mouse location
[-doubleLeftClick] perform a mouse double-click with the left mouse button
[-rightClick] perform a mouse right-click at the current mouse location
[-shiftKey] shift key down, useful when performing a left-click event
[-commandKey] command key down, useful when performing a left-click event
[-optionKey] option key down, useful when performing a left-click event
[-controlKey] control key down, useful when performing a left-click event
[-leftClickNoRelease] perform a mouse click and do not release the mouse click
[-releaseMouse] release the mouse after using -leftClickNoRelease
```

Then create an **Automator** workflow as a Service. Set "No input" as an input and "Preview" as an application. Add this **Apple Script** there:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Preview" to activate
    delay 1
    set mouseToolsPath to (path to home folder as text) & "Downloads:MouseTools"
    tell application "Preview"
        set _b to bounds of the front window
        set _x to item 1 of _b
        set _y to item 2 of _b
        set _width to item 3 of _b
    end tell
    set xpos to _x + (_width / 2)
    set ypos to _y + 10
    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (xpos as text) & " -y " & (ypos as text)
    do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -leftClick"
    return input
end run
```

In this case, my **MouseTools** binary is in `Downloads` directory.
Save it and give it a name You'll remember. Assign keyboard shortcut to this Serivce in **Preferences.app** under *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts*.

I tested this and it works for me.

Comment: 1) Thanks for offering this hint! 2) Can this be sped up? From hitting the shortcut until execution this takes ~2.5secs for me on a rMBP 2014 with OS X 10.9.5 and MouseTools v0.5 (built: 2010-07-31). The menu bar flashes immediately, then there's a delay for 2 secs, then 0.5 for the pop-up animation (avoidable possibly only through other GUI config hack). I want to bring that 2 sec delay down to a few ms. MouseTools in CLI (Terminal) reacts fast, so I suppose Automator/Applescript causes the slowdown.

Comment: If execution of this keyboard shortcut takes 2-3 seconds, than I'm not faster than using the mouse/trackpad. Below 1 second would be my acceptance benchmark in order to prefer the keyboard shortcut over mouse/trackpad.

Comment: @porg Try to remove `delay 1` line in the AppleScript I posted. It waits 1s for Preview activation.

Comment: @ Mateusz or others: Could you please offer an update of the script for macOS 11 Big Sur? The general layout of window title bars changed significantly. In Preview.app too. 1) The title is not centered anymore but more to the left immediately after the first button-bar-block (mostly navigation/view-control buttons). So we need to work with an offset. For starters hardcoded, but maybe there's a more clever method? 2) MouseTools interaction needs updating too. A single left click won't do it. We will need a) "hover for XXXms then click" or b) "double click but avoid window maximization".